# Pass bevy children query elements array to function

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, mutable, bevy

I need to pass an array of children to function. I tried it in two ways:

1. By pushing children to previously created mutable array.
2. with iterator

```
fn object_interactions(
    mut dialog_query: Query<(&mut Style, &mut Children), With<Dialog>>,
    mut element_children: Query<(Option<&mut Text>,Option<&mut Button>, Option<&Interaction>, Entity)>,
// ... more queries ...
) {
    for contact_force_event in contact_force_events.iter() {
        let ContactForceEvent { collider1, collider2, .. } = contact_force_event.clone();
        for (player_entity, mut player, mut player_transform) in player_query.iter_mut() {
            for (mut style, children) in dialog_query.iter_mut() {
                for (object_entity, object) in object_query.iter() {
                    if
                        (collider1 == player_entity && collider2 == object_entity) ||
                        (collider1 == object_entity && collider2 == player_entity)
                    {


// THE IMPORTANT PART - first approach

let mut array_of_elements= vec![];
                        for &child in children.iter() {

                            let result_element = element_children.get_mut(child);

                            if let Ok(element) = result_element {
                                array_of_elements.push(element);
                            }
                            
                        }

// THE IMPORTANT PART - first approach

// THE IMPORTANT PART - second approach

                        let array_of_elements = children.into_iter()
                        .filter_map(|&item| {
                            match element_children.get_mut(item) {
                                Ok(value) => Some(value),
                                Err(_) => None,
                            }
                        })
                        .collect();

// THE IMPORTANT PART - second approach


                        object.interact(
                            // ...different parameters
                            array_of_elements,
                        );



                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the first approach I get:

```
cannot borrow `element_children` as mutable more than once at a time
`element_children` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
```

on result_element. Ofcourse, if I don't push it to this array_of_elements array, there is no error(and actually just nothing, because I am sending empty array then)

On the second approach, I get an error in Some(value) part :

```
captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
`FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape
```

And also some "variable defined here" and "variable captured here" on "element_children" + "inferred to be a `FnMut` closure" on &item inside filter_map